# Is there an easy to switch out of GPU in python

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, cpu

After attempting to utilize my GPU to run a machine learning model, I keep on getting the error "cudaGetDevice() failed. Status: CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version." At this point, I would just like to use my CPU, however, I'm not sure how since every time I try to train my algorithm, it gives the error even though I never imported  the code

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
```

I only ran this code once and now my model can't train Is there an easy way to get rid of this and just go back to train it just with CPU?

Answer (score 1):

This should set it so your tensorflow won't see a cuda GPU when it looks and will default to the CPU.

```
import os
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'
```

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended that you set the [CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/cuda-pro-tip-control-gpu-visibility-cuda_visible_devices/) environment variable to expose different GPUs before starting the processes. Otherwise, TensorFlow will attempt to allocate almost the entire memory on all of the available GPUs, which prevents other processes from using those GPUs (even if the current process isn't using them).

If you set the environment variable `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=-1` you will use the CPU only. If you don't set that environment variable you will allocate memory to all GPUs but by default only use GPU 0. You can also set it to the specific GPU you want to use. `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0` will only use GPU 0.

This environment variable is created by the user, it won't exist until you create it. You need to set the variable before tensorflow is imported (usually that is before you start your script).